# password authentication failed for user "root" when dumping Rails schema as SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using Rails 5.2.3 with PostGIS 2.5 running on Postgres 11, set up in a Docker Compose environment. I've set the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

So that special features in the Schema can get dumped. However, doing so during `db:migrate`, I get the following error:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "development" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

The command that gets executed is:

`pg_dump -s -x -O -f /var/www/dev/db/structure.sql -T geography_columns -T geometry_columns -T layer -T raster_columns -T raster_overviews -T spatial_ref_sys -T topology development`

The reason for the error is that there is no `root` user here; in fact, I am using a different username in my database config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  user: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_POOL") { 10 } %>
```

The user is *not* `root`, and everything works fine from the Rails app itself, which can connect to the database using the user specified in the environment variable.

It just seems that `pg_dump`, when called from Rails to dump the schema, is not using the proper username from the config, but instead falls back to `root`.

I see some configuration [environment variables in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L105), but how should I set them and why does Rails not do that by default?

I think it works when when, in my `docker-compose.yml` file I create an additional environment variable `PGUSER` that has the same value as `DATABASE_USER`. But that seems like workaround — is this a bug I'm seeing or some expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found so far was to specify an additional environment variable named `PGUSER` for the Rails container.

I assume this is a bug or not properly documented.

Comment: Struggled for quite a while with this, thanks @slhck.
For those wondering PGUSER should be set to postgres.